# How to know how many time is a java process awaiting

Tags: java, multithreading, monitoring

I am developing a Java application that has two threads:

- A producer thread that feeds an `ArrayBlockingQueue` at a frequency of 10 KHz (*It is really a C code through JNI*).
- A consumer thread that takes data from the queue, using `take` method, and then process it (*you can't assume the processing time is always the same*). Due to I am using `take` method, this thread can be blocked if no data is available in the queue.

I would like to know how can I monitor or profiling the consumer thread to know how many time it is waiting or blocked.

I am not interested in answers such as taking times with `System.currentTimeMillis()` and taking differences. I want to know how to analyze the whole thread life and sum up how many time has been in every thread state, if this is possible.

How do you do this kind of monitoring?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All sorts of techniques: https://dzone.com/articles/how-analyze-java-thread-dumps

Comment: I already know that article, but I don't know how to get that statistics (*I didn't see how in the article*), maybe it is easy, but I don't know how to do it, so, can you tell me how? That is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any decent Java Profiler can separate statistics by thread, even the otherwise rather basic JVisualVM included with the JDK. Here's a screenshot of JVisualVM watching itself:

[image]

The same information can also be displayed in a table:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very easy indeed, but I never realized that tab contains the statistic I was looking for.